# if td contains this text , is pulling other elements as well

Tags: jquery

I set up a fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/v1bbsm43/3/

I don't have ability to alter the existing HTML on this site, but I'm trying to get some content to append elsewhere, and using contains, it's pulling other data that it shouldn't. I can not find what I'm doing wrong here.

I am just searching the `td` cell for those that have a span class, and then each `span` class contains 1 letter, so i am using `:contains()`, but for some reason other `span` that do not contain that letter are being cloned as well.

```
    $('td.two_column_layout .report td.player:has(.warning):contains(O)').clone().appendTo('#InvalidLineup');
    $('td.two_column_layout .report td.player:has(.warning):contains(P)').clone().appendTo('#InvalidLineup2');
    $('td.two_column_layout .report td.player:has(.warning):contains(Q)').clone().appendTo('#InvalidLineup3');
    $('td.two_column_layout .report td.player:has(.warning):contains(S)').clone().appendTo('#InvalidLineup4');
```

When I use `:contains(S)` or `:contains(O)`, the function is grabbing content that it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because *Beckham, Odell NYG WR* contains O (in Odell) and other such inaccuracies. Add the parenthesis into the contains (for readability, add quotation marks):

```
..:has(.warning):contains("(O)")
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1bbsm43/10/)

> EDIT

After reviewing the code again, and the comments, I found the "real" bug. You separated the `:has(.warning)` part from the `:contains(O)` part. What that does is it looks for a `td.player` that ***has*** any element with class `warning` **AND** ***contains*** the text "O". What you wanted to do is find a `td.player` that has an element with class `warning` **THAT** conatains the text "O" itself. Do that:

```
..:has(.warning:contains(O))
```

2nd working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1bbsm43/16/)

Comment: but the majority of names contain and "O"  , and their name is not part of the span.warning

Comment: *Cruz, Victor NYG WR* doesn't contain "O", and indeed it's not included in the "O" span in your original sample. Check the fiddle, the fix works.

Comment: yes it works , but not understanding why , there are 22 other names no the page that have an O or other letters , but none of them even the one you referenced is not part of the span.warning , for which is being singled out for the text containing . Thank you

Comment: ty , now i understand what was happening